# Is "Penguins of Madagascar" on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

This question has experienced several rounds of closing and reopening:

[Was Dr. Octavius Brine inspired by Octodad?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104077/was-dr-octavius-brine-inspired-by-octodad)

The close justification is that the film is off-topic, with the reasons cited typically being that films with slightly advanced technology and espionage ("spy-fi") or cartoon talking animals are not on-topic.

While I would be in favor of expanding the scope to include some of these works, that is not the issue here.

The problem is that while the two elements mentioned above may not be sufficient for a work to be on-topic, their *absence should not be necessary*.

*Penguins of Madagascar* has plenty of sci-fi/fantasy elements above and beyond its spy-fi or cartoon animal nature.

- There is a ray that turns people into monsters:

  > Skipper: You point that death ray away from Private right now!
  >
  > Private: It's not a death ray, Skipper! He's gonna turn us into
  >   monsters!
- The ray also causes penguins to sprout supernumerary appendages.

  > Dave: Yepper-doo! And what comes next, Dave? Invasion! Ahhh!
  >   Horrible mutant penguins released on the streets of New York City!
  >
  > Skipper: Private, are you okay?
  >
  > Private: Yes!
  >
  > Skipper, Rico and Kowalski gasp in surprise and notice that Private
  >   has sprouted a hand out of his buttocks.
  >
  > Kowalski: Whoa! Butt-hand! There’s a hand attached to his butt. That
  >   was not... that was not there before.
- The polarity of the uglification ray can be reversed through cuteness, which frankly is more fantasy than sci-fi.

  > In order to reverse the ray, we would need to replace the Medusa Serum
  >   with a power source of almost immeasurable cuteness.

  Personally, this last one convinces me that it is on-topic. It's very MLP, isn't it?
- The Wiki insists that Octavius Brine was once human and turned into an octopus, but this is not confirmed elsewhere (I'd like to ask this question if the series is deemed on-topic, though).

It seemed to me that such a contentious issue called for a Meta consensus, so: Is *Penguins of Madagascar* on-topic?

Comment: Also, _Octodad_ may be on topic, making the question on topic. Is _Octodad_ on topic?

Comment: And if either Penguins of Madagascar or Octodad are declared off topic, what should happen to their tags? (I only care about the Scope Wars to the extent that they spill into the Tag Wars.)

Comment: @anaranjada - Nothing much. Questions about the sci-fi elements will still be on-topic, so they might need to be altered a bit to reflect that.

Comment: But if they have no sci-fi elements (possible for Octodad--I don't know), then the tag wiki will say something like, "for questions about how Octodad relates to speculative fiction works", which I suppose almost makes sense... [This meta question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/what-should-we-do-with-a-tag-thats-used-only-for-questions-closed-as-off-topic) doesn't have an answer that applies to works entirely devoid of sci-fi/fantasy elements.

Comment: Remember, vote on answers to show your opinions.

Comment: I could write an answer saying, "I'm staying out of this..."

Comment: @SQB: The story of *Octodad* is about an octopus who pretends to be a human, and his enemy, a sushi chef who wants to out him as an octopus. They live in a dark age when octopuses had no human rights at all, and the sushi chef could have killed and cooked him as long as he can prove he's an octopus.  That clearly isn't a fantasy story about aliens, that's basically real historical fiction about the state of certain ethnical minorities in Europe between 1930 and 1970.

Comment: The story doesn't even try to talk about justifications of why a certain minority should or should not have human rights.  Compare this to eg. Asimov's *The Bicentennial Man*, which does talk a lot about which parts of Andrew the people suppose make him different from humans.  That makes it a sci-fi novel.

Comment: Also, feel free to post your own answer if mine do not cover what you think.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it should be on-topic. There are sufficient sci-fi or fantasy elements.

Comment: They use sci fi tech, they're talking animals, there's magic in at least one point, and they're in the same universe as the guys who turned a circus into a UFO and flew it over Europe. Yes.

Comment: Dont forget, whether it fully meets on topic requirements, we can choose to make it ontopic ANYWAY

Comment: The fact that it has talking animals isn't enough to make it on-topic. The fact that it has death rays and UFOs is.

Answer (score -1):

No, it should not be on-topic. There are insufficient sci-fi or fantasy elements, or spy-fi/cartoon animals disqualifies it.

Comment: FWIW, I was advised by [Robert Cartaino](http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/users/2/robert-cartaino) that this kind of [polling on Meta isn't really effective](http://meta.crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/96/would-we-want-to-show-preference-for-tags-using-plural-versions/105#comment247_104)

Comment: @CreationEdge - Maybe. Perhaps it's the worst system, except for all the others. I'm not a mod, so I can't superping everyone and ask their opinions.

Comment: @Jonah This definitely isn't the best way to resolve a policy-setting meta discussion. In the future, if we refer users who're interested in *Penguins of Madagascar* to this thread, all they'll be able to see is "some bunch of anonymous users voted this way or that". If people had answered this question instead with "it should be on-topic/off-topic BECAUSE blah blah blah", the thread would have much more lasting value and be more useful to future readers.

Comment: I'm sorry, @Rand. I had seen this elsewhere, so it seemed an acceptable technique. Also, I *thought* I had talked to a mod about it.

Comment: @Randal'Thor You mean like we do with *every* policy set on meta?